# How to become the verified publisher of a Snap package

Tags: security, snap

I published a Snap package in the Snap Store and I want to appear as a verified publisher because I am the developer of this app. It's open source and I manage the github repository.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, it is **not possible** to become a verified publisher.

From Canonical's Snapcraft forum, [quoting Community Manager Alan Pope](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-to-become-verified-publisher/7442/2):

> We’ve currently verified a selected group of developers on the snap
>   store. We have no current plans to expand that much more widely, nor
>   publish details of a process for becoming verified.

No further information or explanation is provided.

Comment: I see checkmarks next to publishers on the Snap Store, so it seems like this answer is out of date.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply to become a verified publisher. The process is described [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/verified-accounts/34002), targeted at organizations and involving a peer-reviewed process. Verified publisher accounts get a check mark (✓).

As an individual maintainer, you may instead want to get your account recognized as a [Star Developer](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/star-developers/30714). Start Developer accounts get a star (✪).

Both come with added maintenance responsibility for the published snaps.